# Definition of homogeneous or quasi-uniform or almost uniform measure

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory

Let us call a measure $\Lambda$ homogeneous if there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that for all $r>0$ and $x,y$ in the support of $\Lambda$, we have

$$\Lambda(B(x,r))>\epsilon\Lambda(B(y,r))$$

where as usual $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$.  I am thinking of $\mathbb{R}^d$ but it could be a general metric space.  **Q: Is this (equivalent to) a known definition in the literature?**

**Update:** I followed up dirk's comment to user116082's answer.  Google scholar gives me exactly 10 results for "quasi uniform measure."  The two that seem relevant are

[Saul Jacka and Jon Warren, "Random orderings of the integers and card shuffling," Stochastic Processes and their Applications, 117, 708-719 (2007).](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414906001426)

which is quite a different concept.  Also

[É Janvresse and T. de la Rue, "A class of pairwise-independent joinings," Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems, 28, 1545-1557 (2008).](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385707000958)

which is very close to what I have applied to cylinder sets in symbolic dynamics.  The latter paper gives the definition but is worded in a way that suggests it is a known concept.  The relevant reference [5] in that paper does not appear to contain this terminology, though (searching using google books).

So, for now, the original question still stands, for more general contexts than symbolic dynamics, and also **Q2: What is the first usage of the term quasi-uniform measure as defined in the second paper above?**

**Update 2:** Repeating the above process for "almost uniform measure" yields 11 google scholar results, one of which gives a definition that looks equivalent to the above, except for all points in the space, not just in the support of the measure.

For example, the usual measure on the middle third Cantor set satisfies the above definition in $\mathbb{R}$ but the "almost uniform measure" definition only if the space is the Cantor set itself with metric induced from its embedding into $\mathbb{R}$.

The relevant reference is

[M. Studený, "On the differentiation theorem in metric groups." Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae 24 223-232 (1983).](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106221/CommentatMathUnivCarol_024-1983-2_3.pdf)

On balance, it seems best to stick with "almost uniform measure" but note the above distinction with regard to the support.  I am still interested in any further references or information about these definitions.

Comment: Context? What is $\Lambda$?

Comment: Thanks @Ycor - it's a measure and I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: In my experience, the word "homogeneous" is used throughout mathematics almost exclusively to mean "invariant under a transitive group action". Perhaps you might look for an adjective which is less likely to lead the reader to make a mistake about what you mean.

Comment: This reminds me of the definition of [doubling measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space#Doubling_Measures) in harmonic analysis.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, I am aware of some literature on doubling measures.  I think my definition implies that the measure is doubling.

Comment: Not an answer, only tangentially related: it reminds me of a notion you can find by searching 'measure with bounded density'. Also, [this M.SE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680397/lipschitz-and-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-measures) is somehow relevant (let $\epsilon:=\frac{1}{C}$ and let $\Lambda:=\mu:=\nu$, with $C$, $\mu$, $\nu$ as in loc. cit. In this thread, 'measure of bounded density' has been recommended as the direction-in-knowledge space to look along. Of course, in the present case, it is only required for a subset of the sigma-algebra.

Comment: By "context" I expect a little more... probably you mean a Borel measure on $\mathbf{R}^d$, and I don't know if you assume it's finite, or Radon, or anything.

Comment: @Ben Some of the literature on doubling measures uses the notation (C,s)-homogeneous measures.  Other literature related to mine uses epsilon-homogeneous for a related property.  Do you have any suggestions for an alternative adjective that is not widely used/confused?

Comment: @Peter Do you mean anything other than a measure absolutely continuous with respect to lebesgue with a bounded density?  Searching led only to a fairly random collection of papers.  Perhaps you have a particular reference in mind?  I agree that this notion is relevant, but I am also interested in singular, eg fractal measures.

Comment: @YCor Fair question, although the lack of detailed context was somewhat deliberate - I don't really care how general/different the other literature/usage might be and didn't want to bias the answers.  I am using the measure as an intensity for Poisson Point Processes, and so Radon would be good.  My definition only makes sense if the measure of a ball is finite, not necessarily that of the whole space.

Comment: @Carl: I did not mean anything more specific than what you stated. I am sorry not to have made it even clearer that this is only very tangential. The link to the M.SE site is slightly more relevant, but also not really an answer.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, your comment was helpful in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, being anonymous, and this is not a true answer to the question.

Your notion is similar to the notion of a [uniformly distributed measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_distributed_measure) used in geometric measure theory. That is a measure that assigns the (exact) same mass to all balls of the same radius.

Your measure only assigns uniformly comparable mass to all balls of the same radius. I might therefore call it ``quasi-uniformly distributed'' although this is a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: What about a "quasi uniform" or "almost uniform" measure?